# Vue v-if not affect to Dom when using interval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I'm trying to make polling with `setInterval` and rendering some element conditionally with Vue. But it's not working, so I set my data to `true` but on DOM nothing happened.

P.S: I'm using Vue.js with CDN so my app not created with VueCLI.

here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 v-if="showtext">
      text
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my script. When coming response with status 200, my data it's switching to true. I can see it on console but my text not rendering on DOM.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    polling: null,
    showtext: false
  },
  methods: {
    pollData() {
      this.polling = setInterval(() => {
        axios({
          method: "get",
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.showtext = true
          }
          console.log(this.showtext)
        });
      }, 7000);
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.polling);
  },
  created() {
    this.pollData();
  },
});
```

Comment: i bet the `this` is wrong inside the axios callback. log just `this` and see. as you have it, you can't really tell if that's the problem because you only check what you set, not what it's attached to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// You have lost context in this function, use arrow function instead
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status == 200) {
    this.showtext = true
  }
  console.log(this.showtext)
});
```

Something like this:

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status == 200) {
    this.showtext = true
  }
  console.log(this.showtext)
});
```

Comment: thanks it's worked. Can u tell me what's a trick with arrow function? and arrow function will work in old browsers too?

Comment: Arrow functions lexically bind their context so `this` actually refers to the originating context.

Comment: In your case you have lost `this`, that was pointing to Vue instance, but using arrow function you can save that context to access `showtext` property.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an arrow function like in order to get access to the vue instance scope:

```
 then((response)=> { ...
```

or assign `this` to a global variable as follows (this works with old browsers) :

```
    var that=this; ///<------ 
  axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
              }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.status == 200) {
                  that.showtext = true
                }
                console.log(that.showtext)
              });
```

**Full running example :**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

     var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
          return{
          polling: null,
          showtext:false
          }
        },
        methods: {
          pollData() {
            this.polling = setInterval(() => {
              axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
              }).then((response)=> {
               
                if (response.status == 200) {
                  this.showtext = true
                }
                console.log(this.showtext)
              });
            }, 4000);
          }
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
          clearInterval(this.polling);
        },
        created() {
          this.pollData();
        },
      });
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-axios@2.1.4/dist/vue-axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <div class="container">
      test:
        <h1 v-if="showtext">
          text
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Why my text is not getting rendered ?

because `this.showtext` that you see on the console is not the one on your `$data` object ... it's a globlal variable `window.showtext` because the `this` bidden  to `then` is `window` .

## solution:

you have to bind your vue instance `this` instead to your `then` :

you can do it by using:

```
then((response) => {}) (which binds this implicitly)
```

or :

```
then((function(response) { ... }).bind(this) )
```